# How to place a function from another class in add_action 2nde argument?

Tags: plugins

I would like to use a function from class B as a second argument of the add_action() function of class A, here is what I tried for now (I simply created an instance of class B in class A):

```
class A
{

    public function __construct()

    {

        include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/classB.php';

        $classB= new classB();

        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_admin_menu'), 20);

    }



    public function add_admin_menu()

    {

            add_menu_page('Plugin Back End', 'Back End Plugin', 'manage_options', 'backend', array($this, 'menu_html'));


            $hook_heb = add_submenu_page('backend', 'hebergements', 'hebergements', 'manage_options', 'hebergements', array($this, 'menu_hebergements'));

            add_action('load-'.$hook_heb, array($this, 'process_action_heb'));

    }

}
```

classB.php

```
class Hebergement

{



    public function process_action_heb()

    {

        if (isset($_POST['send_hebergement'])) {

            $this->send_hebergement();

        }

    }
    ............;;
```

In wordpress admin panel I get this error:

> class 'Other_Part' does not have a method 'process_action_heb' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Anyone as a solution for this problem ?

Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to callback the `process_action_heb` method from `$this` (aka class A) and it's not a method of the A class - it's a method of B.

I'd use dependency injection to solve this, though you could use a method like you're using.

```
//* plugin.php
include_once PATH_TO . '/classA.php';
include_once PATH_TO . '/classB.php';

$classB = new classB();
$classA = new classA( $classB );

add_action( 'hookA', [ $classA, 'some_method' ], 20 );

//* class-a.php
class A {
  protected $classB;
  public function __construct( $classB ) {
    $this->classB = $classB;
  }
  public function some_method() {
    //* Do something

    //* And add action to classB::some_method
    add_action( 'hookB', [ $this->classB, 'some_method' ] );
  }
}

//* class-b.php
class B {
  public function some_method() {
    //* This code will run on the hookB hook
  }
}
```